# How java.util.function.Function can have a method reference of Object class toString method

Tags: java

```
Function<Integer, String> intToString = Object::toString
```

above code is example for method reference

Please help me how it works.

As per my understanding method reference should have the same method signature as Functional Interface abstract method( R apply(T) ).

Comment: `Function<Integer, String>` is something which can consume an integer and will return a string. `Object::toString` can consume an integer (and indeed any object) and return a string. Thus, it matches.

Comment: `Object::toString` (accepts an `Object`) is not the same thing as `someObject::toString` (accepts nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're right. To assign something to a variable declared like

```
Function<Integer, String> intToString = value;
```

then `value` has to be a `Function<Integer, String>`, something that has a

```
public String apply(Integer t) { ... }
```

method.

The tricky thing is that a method reference expression like `Object::toString` is syntactic sugar for

```
Function<Integer, String> intToString = new Function<Integer,String>() {
    public String apply(Integer t) { 
        return t.toString();
    }
};
```

And how does it know the `Integer` and `String` type parameters that aren't mentioned in just the expression `Object::toString`? That comes from the left-hand side of the assignment. The compiler knows what type of function is expected and creates an appropriate inner, anonymous `Function` instance from the method reference `Object::toString`.

Caveat: A method reference `Object::toString` is only allowed in situations where the compiler can clearly deduce what type is expected, as this expression's type is unclear. Depending on the context (e.g. left-hand side), the very same `Object::toString` can as well become a `Consumer<Point>` instead of a `Function<Integer, String>`, then implementing a method `void accept(Point t)`.